# How do I define a unique button type?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two input tags so for this example I want to have two buttons that can the change color of a text or italicize. In my function I call the button, but they are not unique. My "change color" button will also italicize and vice versa which makes sense. How can I fix this?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").click(function(){
    $('#myForm [type="text"]').css("color", "red");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").click(function(){
    $('#myForm [type="text"]').css("font-style", "italic");
  });
});
```

```css
.table {
    border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
             <th>text</th>
             <th>change color</th>
             <th>italicize</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value="HELLO WORLD!"></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="change color"></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="italicize"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: um, your selectors are exactly the same.... So they both select every input on the page and add event handlers to it. So you need to add a class or id to select the element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use unique id or classes, I added 2 different classes to buttons `italicBtn` and `colorBtn` and changed your click event listeners

PS you don't have to use `$(document).ready(function(){` twice, just place your code inside one `ready` function

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".colorBtn").click(function(){
    $('#myForm [type="text"]').css("color", "red");
  });
  $(".italicBtn").click(function(){
    $('#myForm [type="text"]').css("font-style", "italic");
  });
});
```

```css
.table {
    border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
             <th>text</th>
             <th>change color</th>
             <th>italicize</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value="HELLO WORLD!"></td>
            <td><input type="button" class="colorBtn" value="change color"></td>
            <td><input type="button" class="italicBtn" value="italicize"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a class to distinguish the button or you can use the value property. All with the keyword **this** that refers to the current button:

```js
$("input").click(function(){
    if (this.value == 'change color') {
        $(this).css("color", "red");
    } else {
        $(this).css("font-style", "italic");
    }
});
```

```css
.table {
    border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form id="myForm">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>text</th>
            <th>change color</th>
            <th>italicize</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value="HELLO WORLD!"></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="change color"></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="italicize"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thats smart, but if he decides to change value of button he will also have to change it in js. Thats little bit of spaghetti code if u ask me. Maybe you should use index of button to distinguish the two.

Comment: @JonNezbit You are right. Using a class or an attribute would have been better

Comment: Not rly necessary. I think that he could get away with using indexes of buttons but thats just me.

Comment: An index of a button is just as fragile, if not more, than the value of an attribute.

Comment: @JonNezbit I'm sorry but using idexes is the same if he change the order.....

Comment: If you want to go this way, use a [`data-*` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

Comment: @ScottMarcus  Right scott

Comment: @gaetanoM when I think about it, maybe you are right. Data attribute is also smart idea

Answer (score 2):

You should add a class instead of the inline changes and toggle between the classes with jQuery.

Read more about jQuery's [.toggleClass](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) method.

Also, you should use `id`s to get the button click event and to change the input.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button-red").click(function(){
    $("#input").toggleClass("red");
  });
  $("#button-italic").click(function(){
    $("#input").toggleClass("italic");
  });
});
```

```css
.table {
    border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif;
}

.red{
  color: red;
}

.italic{
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
             <th>text</th>
             <th>change color</th>
             <th>italicize</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input id="input" type="text" value="HELLO WORLD!"></td>
            <td><input id="button-red" type="button" value="change color"></td>
            <td><input id="button-italic" type="button" value="italicize"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give each button a unique `id` or `class` and set up the event based on that particular element.

You can do the same thing with the `input` so that you don't have to search for it by its attribute value.

Lastly, you can set up both event handlers inside of just one `document.ready`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  let $input = $("#input");  // Get the reference to the input just once
  
  $("#color").click(function(){
    $input.css("color", "red");
  });
  
  $("#italics").click(function(){
    $input.css("font-style", "italic");
  });
});
```

```css
.table {
    border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
             <th>text</th>
             <th>change color</th>
             <th>italicize</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="input" value="HELLO WORLD!"></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="color" value="change color"></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="italics" value="italicize"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine things that are alike each other by using data attributes.

```js
$("input[data-style]").on("click", function() {
  var btn = $(this);
  $('#myForm [type="text"]').css(btn.data('style'), btn.data('value'));
});
```

```css
.table {
  border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>text</th>
        <th>change color</th>
        <th>italicize</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value="HELLO WORLD!"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="change color" data-style="color" data-value="red"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="italicize" data-style="font-style" data-value="italic"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```